# Proving an asymptotic property regard the fraction of ‘1’ and ‘0’ in binary sequences

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory

Consider the set of sequences of zeroes and ones of length $N$ with $k$ ones (or, $Np$ ones where $p = k/N$). We draw randomly and uniformly a sequence from this set.

I want to show that with probability tending to $1$ as $N\to\infty$, there are approximately $kN/2$ (or $Np/2$) ones in the first half of this sequence.

Thank you!

Comment: You want exactly $Np$ 1's, where $p$ is a real number in $(0,1)$?  What if $p$ is irrational?

Comment: You right, in the case of irrational $p$ we can't have exactly $Np$ 1's. However, for very large $N$ we can approximate it with "error" small as we want.

By the way, in this site : http://j.ee.washington.edu/~bilmes/classes/ee515a_spring_2012/lecture7_print.pdf

you can find a lecture notes in which there are some nice properties of type class (starting from page 13 in the pdf), which maybe will help. But, I can't see how :(

Comment: Could you describe more precisely the typical set when Np is not an integer?

Comment: Yes. Maybe the definition in words that I gave is little confusing.
 
Type (for binary sequence)- a type of a binary sequence is the relative proportion of occurrences of $1$ and $0$, i.e. $P_{x^N}(0)$ and $P_{x^N}(1)$ which I have defined earlier.
 
Type class $T(P)$ - is the set of sequences of length $N$ with type $P$.

Now, if for example we consider the type class $T(0.1)$ for $N=2$ then the type class is of curse empty. However, in the question, we consider very large $N$, so we can approximate it with "error" small as we want. Thank you !

Comment: *we consider very large N, so we can approximate it with "error" small as we want*... You already said that, but how can we approximate?

Comment: The set of all types $\mathcal{P}_n$ in the binary case is $\mathcal{P}_n = [(0,\frac{n}{n}),(\frac{1}{n},\frac{n-1}{n}),...,(\frac{n}{n},0)]$. So, since the rationals are dense subset of the real numbers, for very large n we can approach any type. Did this answers your question, or, I am missing something?

Comment: *this answers your question*... Not really, see my answer for a rigorous setting.

Comment: Hmm..I see. If we can assume that $Np$ is always an integer, do you see another simple solution? Moreover, I can't see how it hurts your solution, which I think very general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\mathbb S(n,k)$ as the set of sequences of zeroes and ones of length $n$ with $k$ ones. A crucial fact is that one can draw randomly uniformly an element of $\mathbb S(n,k)$ by conditioning the uniform distribution on the set $\{0,1\}^n$.

To be more precise, consider some i.i.d. random variables $(X_i)_{i\geqslant i}$ uniformly distributed on $\{0,1\}$ and $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$. Then, conditionally on $[S_n=k]$, the random element $(X_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$ is uniformly distributed on $\mathbb S(n,k)$.

By symmetry, $x=\mathbb E(X_i\mid S_n=k)$ and $y=\mathbb E(X_iX_j\mid S_n=k)$ do not depend on $i\ne j$ between $1$ and $n$. Summing these and using the fact that $X_i^2=X_i$ for every $i$, one gets $x=k/n$ and
$$
k^2=n\mathbb E(X_i^2\mid S_n=k)+n(n-1)\mathbb E(X_iX_j\mid S_n=k)=k+n(n-1)y,
$$
hence 
$$
y=\frac{k(k-1)}{n(n-1)}.
$$
For every $i\leqslant n$, one gets $\mathbb E(S_i\mid S_n=k)=ix$ and
$$
\mathrm{var}(S_i\mid S_n=k)=ix+i(i-1)y-i^2x^2=z,
$$
where
$$
z=\frac{ik(n-i)(n-k)}{n^2(n-1)}.
$$
Let $\varepsilon$ denote a positive parameter, and $\mathbb S(n,k,i,\varepsilon)$ the portion of the set $\mathbb S(n,k)$ made of sequences of zeroes and ones of length $n$ with $k$ ones such that the initial fragment of length $i$ has less than $(1-\varepsilon)ik/n$ or more than $(1+\varepsilon)ik/n$ ones.

Then the size of $\mathbb S(n,k,i,\varepsilon)$ divided by the size of $\mathbb S(n,k)$ is exactly the probability of the event $[|S_i-\mathbb E(S_i)|\geqslant\varepsilon ix]$, which, by Bienaymé-Chebychev inequality, is
$$
\mathbb P(|S_i-\mathbb E(S_i)|\geqslant\varepsilon ix\mid S_n=k)\leqslant\frac{z}{\varepsilon^2i^2x^2}=\frac{A(n,k,i)}{\varepsilon^2},
$$
with
$$
A(n,k,i)=\frac{(n-i)(n-k)}{ik(n-1)}.
$$
In other words, for every $(n,k,i,\varepsilon)$, the proportion of sequences in $\mathbb S(n,k)$ whose initial portion of length $i$ has a number of ones which differs of its mean value $ik/n$  by more than $\varepsilon ik/n$, is at most $A(n,k,i)/\varepsilon^2$.

Now the asymptotics come into play. Assume that $n\to+\infty$, that $k/n\to p$ for some $p$ in $(0,1)$ and that $i/n\to1/2$. One sees that $nA(n,k,i)\to(1-p)/p$ hence $A(n,k,i)\to0$. This proves the desired result, for every positive $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Very nice and clean answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note that really you only care about the first half of the sequence -- if the first half has error at most $\epsilon p N$, then the second half has the same discrepancy.  The expected number of $1$'s in the first $N/2$ terms is equal to $Np/2$, which we'll denote by $\mu$.  You want to bound the probability that 
$$|\sum_{i=1}^{N/2} x_i - \mu| \geq \epsilon Np = 2 \epsilon \mu$$

In this form the situation looks a lot like the ones on which we can use the [Chernoff Bound](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jfc/cs174/lecs/lec10/lec10.pdf) (see in particular the "simplify it to a weaker bound" mentioned on page 2). But there's a slight catch -- the $x_i$ are in this case not independent due to the requirement that the whole sequence contains $pN$ $1$s.

However, the correlation in a sense goes in the "right direction": If the sum up to $k$ is unusually large, that makes it more likely that the next term will be $0$ (because there's an unusually large number of $0's$ remaining), which will tend to drive things back towards the mean.  More formally, this is referred to as being "negatively associated".  Intuitively, negative association should be a *good* thing for us -- it makes it harder to get a sum far away from the mean.

This turns out to be true -- the same Chernoff bounds that hold for independent variables also hold for any set of negatively associated variables (for more on this, see the beginning of [this survey by Dubhashi and Ranjan](http://www.brics.dk/RS/96/25/BRICS-RS-96-25.pdf)).  So we can just apply the Chernoff bounds directly, which immediately give a bound exponentially small in $N$ for fixed $p$ and $\epsilon$.

---

Actually, it's not even the full strength of negative association which is needed here.  When you have a sum of indicator variables, all you need is negative correlation: That for any $S$ and any $i \notin S$, we have $$P(x_i=1 | x_j=1 \forall j \in S) \leq P(x_i=1),$$
which can be easily checked to hold for your model.
  For the proof of Chernoff to go through, the important fact is that for positive $t$, we have to have $$E(\prod e^{tx_i}) \leq \prod E( e^{t x_i}).$$
To see that this holds for negatively correlated variables, note that: 
\begin{eqnarray*} E(\prod_{i=1}^n e^{tx_i}) &=& E\left(\prod_{i=1}^n (1+(e^t-1) x_i)\right)  \\
&=& \sum_{S \subseteq \{1, \dots N\}} (e^t-1)^{|S|} P(x_i=1 \textrm{ for all } i \in S) \textrm{ (by the binomial theorem)} \\
&\leq& \sum_{S \subseteq \{1, \dots N\}} (e^t-1)^{|S|} p^{|S|} \textrm{ (using negative correlation) }\\
&=& \left(1+p(e^t-1)\right)^N \textrm{ (recombining using binomial theorem)}\\
&=& \prod_{i=1}^N E(e^{tx_i})
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Nice! Thank you! I didn't know the "negatively associated" property. Behind intuition, how can I prove the negatively associated in this case?

Comment: I think negative association is actually a bit of overkill here, and negative correlation (which is much easier to check) is enough.  I've added a bit of detail on this.

Comment: Very nice..Thank you!